# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sink'

Tags: python, oop, attributeerror

I need to develop a demo ETL system that need to run from following fluent python format

> ETL().source(source_args).sink(sink_args).run()

I made the `class ETL()` after this I made a function `source` and function `sink` in the class.
Code looks like this:

```py
class ETL:

    def source(self, data_source: str):
        if data_source == 'Simulation':
            simulation()
        elif data_source == 'File':
            main()

    def sink(self, data_sink: str):
        if data_sink == 'Console':
            command = 'Continue'
            user_command = input('Please type to Continue or to Stop!')
            while command != 'Stop':
                simulation()

        else:
            pass

ETL().source('Simulation').sink('Console')
```

When I run the file I receive this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sink'

Where I am wrong and how to add the last method `.run()`?
I take `simulation()` function from another file but this is not the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to use a `fluent` interface?

Comment: Just to  be more readable I suppose

Comment: What is a `fluent` interface?

Comment: Anyway you know how to fix AttributeError

Comment: Well, of course. I'm just trolling you because you are using buzz words and haven't done any research. btw what do you think that the `run()` method will do?

Comment: It will start the program but I don't know how to implement it So this is like a test I need to do if you know any material where I can read witch will help me Please share

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234206/discussion-between-quamrana-and-mikegrep).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fluent interface with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827808/fluent-interface-with-python)

Comment: Simply put, your .source() method does not `return` a value. If a python function or method does not return a value, then by default it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found the answer anyway, but I'll just add some `return self` to your code:

```py
class ETL:

    def source(self, data_source: str):
        if data_source == 'Simulation':
            simulation()
        elif data_source == 'File':
            main()
        return self

    def sink(self, data_sink: str):
        if data_sink == 'Console':
            command = 'Continue'
            user_command = input('Please type to Continue or to Stop!')
            while command != 'Stop':
                simulation()
        return self

ETL().source('Simulation').sink('Console')
```

The above code will now work without the error.

However, you also ask about the `run()` method. I want to know what that is supposed to do. To me it looks like the `sink()` method, having a `while` loop is doing the *run* thing.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```py
# code elided ...
    def sink(self, data_sink: str):
        self.data_sink = data_sink
        return self

    def run(self):
        if self.data_sink == 'Console':
            command = 'Continue'
            user_command = input('Please type to Continue or to Stop!')
            while command != 'Stop':
                simulation()

# Now this will work:
ETL().source(source_args).sink(sink_args).run()
```

Comment: Yes that is what I need It will help me a lot and the point is I get it now how its work Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem here is that your method `source()` does not return anything, so you recibe a `None` as ouput. Then when applying the second method (`sink()`) you are not doing it any more with an instance of `ETL` but with the output of `ETL().source('Simulation')`. You should try something like this:

```
foo = ETL()
foo.source('Simulation')
foo.sink('Console')
```

Another solution (although I don't think it's the best way to do this) is that you returned `self` in the `source` method. That would allow you to continue working with the instance of your class, and running the line of code you want.

Comment: Its need to be in following format 

    ETL().source(source_args).sink(sink_args).run()

Comment: @mikegrep: but are you getting the clues that both these answers are pointing you to?

Comment: If you really need it in that format then try adding `return self` in every method. I don't know what you're doing but I don't think this is a good solution to the problem. I just guess it might work anyway.

Comment: Yes with `'return self` is working any advice how to implement and the wast method `run()`

Answer (score 3):

NoneType means that instead of an instance of the ETL which you want to call, you've actually got None. That's because the function call failed or returned an unexpected result.

A way to change that would be to add a return to your functions.

The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object's constructor as the target argument with sequential and keyword arguments taken from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively. Each time an object is created a method is called. That methods is named the constructor.

The constructor is created with the function init. As parameter we write the self keyword, which refers to itself (the object). The function init(self) builds your object. Its not just variables you can set here, you can call class methods too. Everything you need to initialize the object(s). It could look something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
       self.source()
       self.sink()
```

Comment: Sorry, but that still isn't the answer. The OP has `class ETL` which can be instantiated with `ETL()`, and so `ETL().source(...)` is also valid. Although your recent edit gets closer to the problem.

Comment: Yes I agree the function is have return statment

Comment: What do you think the `return` statements should look like?

Comment: @quamrana Can you check if this is how it's working or am I on the wrong path here?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to have an `__init__()` method, nor for it to do all the processing. See the duplicate and my answer for where I think the OP is heading.